# How to get everyday AM 9:00 compare with Android System time?

Tags: android

Here is my situation. The method TodayFirst I want to get everyday AM 9:00 and compare with Android System time. But I run this method it will get the System time.

```
public String TodayFirst()
{
    String time ="";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
    time = df.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Its really unclear what exactly you trying to do . But to get Exact 9AM time add `calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE,0);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND,0);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND,0);`.

Comment: Check this example [link](https://www.stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)

Comment: and what is the problem? What are you missing, or what is wrong with the code?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. You can assume any basic date-time Question has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 You could do as belows:
    public String TodayFirst()
    {
        String time;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(df.format(date));
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
        calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE,0);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND,0);

        time = df.format(calendar.getTime());
        return time;  //time will be 2018/08/28 09:00:00 if you call the function today
    }
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted by the *java.time* classes years ago. See the modern approach taken in the [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52052116/642706)

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (now.isAfter(LocalTime.of(9, 0))) {
        System.out.println("It’s past 9");
    }
```

Notice how much clearer it reads than the code in your question.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` (with subpackages).

### What went wrong in your code?

You need a return statement in your method. Assuming you wanted to return `time`, the method produces a string like `2018/08/28 09:21:03`. The hours have been set to 9, but the minutes and seconds are unchanged from the current time. Also you are producing a similar string for current system time, but not comparing the two.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use Alarm Manager.
[from here you get how to use Alarm Manage.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25986730/3713967)

Alarm manager work on system clock

This alarm manager will send one broadcast at every 9:00 Am. using that Broadcast you can do for other stuff.